# gnuplot_x11 process remains active after closing the plot window

Tags: process, gnuplot, ksh

I searched with Google and on this site but couldn't find any solution to the following problem.
I'm using a ksh function to plot some graphics but need to keep the main gnuplot process open so the plot window (gnuplot_x11) remains interactive, reacting to keyboard shortcuts, zooming in, etc. At the same time I want to continue working on the command-line. So I start gnuplot in the background and in a while loop I check every second if the gnuplot_x11 process was terminated. If yes, then I would kill the main gnuplot process. The problem is that when I close the plot window the gnuplot_x11 process does not disappear from the 'ps' list:

```
$ ps -fu $USER
    UID      PID     PPID   C    STIME    TTY  TIME CMD
user 21037096 55378014   0 09:09:07  pts/1  0:00 gnuplot
user 52428898 21037096   0 09:09:11  pts/1  0:00 gnuplot_x11
user 55378014   721428   0 08:37:56  pts/1  0:02 -ksh
```

How can I find out if the plot window was closed?

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me a clue. Adding the command "pause mouse close" after the plot command does the trick. The main gnuplot process waits until the plot window is closed by the user.